# Python how to return index and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Let

```
a = [1,2,2,3,1,4,2]
```

In Matlab I can find the index and values as follows:

```
[val, idx] = find(a>=2);
```

the output will be

```
val = [2,2,4,2]
idx = [2,3,6,7]
```

What is the easiest way to do this in Python?

Comment: `val = 2` and `idx = a.index(val)`?

Comment: It will only return index of first occurrence @Delgan, isn't it ?

Comment: @akashkarothiya Yeah, I do not know Matlab very well. Is the expected output a list of `[val, idx]`?

Comment: Please try to improve your question by specifying the expected output in Python.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I think there is no straightforward way to do this in (raw) Python. The `val` list seems a bit redundant, right?

Comment: I have modified the question :)

Comment: All your the values in `idx` are shifted by `+1` to be properly defined python indeces as they start from `0` not `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EDIT` : Since you modified your question, here is the updated answer

```
>>> index, values = zip(*[(index, data) for index, data in enumerate(a) if data >= 2 ])
>>> values
(2, 2, 3, 4, 2)
>>> index
(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)
```

You can simply use `list comprehension` to get all the index occurence

```
>>> a = [1,2,2,3,1,4,2]
>>> val = 2
>>> [index for index, data in enumerate(a) if data == val ]
[1, 2, 6]
```

But if you want to maintain value as well, You can also dig it as tuple :

```
>>> index, val = [ index for index, data in enumerate(a) if data == val ], val
>>> index, val
([1, 2, 6], 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, since you're comparing with matlab, would be for you to use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,2,3,1,4,2])
a >= 2  # Just to check what you get by doing this boolean operation
values = a[a>=2]  # using the conditional to filter a numpy array
indeces = np.argwhere(a>=2).reshape(-1)  # to get the indices
```